# Could someone recommend me methodologies to be a better UX designer?

Tags: design, research, ux-designer, methodology, resources

I've been working as a UX designer for a couple of years. I've been improving my skills doing courses in websites like IDF (Interaction design foundation).Also , daily I research about better practices which can help to improve the experience of the users.

I work on a company which offers different kind of services through websites and apps like search jobs, rent and buy homes, etc...
My main work duties are researching about better practices, wireframes, usability testing, qualitative research, etc...

In spite of my experience i've realized that several of my ideas and suggestions (I mean specifically new elements of an interface, suggestions of flows and different elements of interaction) are not enough to improve the experience of the clients and to attract new users.

Can someone recommend me methodologies which have worked to you, resources that I can research or just a piece of advice in order to improve my work as a UX designer?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This book has gone out of print, try and see if you can pick a second hand/electronic copy, it has a tonne of stuff for discovering and refining UX practises https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8675550-smashing-ux-design

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but to me it sounds like you are operating alone in the field of UX. My experience is that you learn the most and get new insights by working together with other designers. Methodologies and methods are one thing, but actually performing and reflecting on them together with other designers is what makes you learn. I hope it's a possibility for you. IF you are operating alone right now.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you expand the definition of UX outside interfaces. Start thinking about the physical world, customer service, daily life of the customers, the B2B side, etc. If you think the interface is optimized enough and you are still not seeing results, maybe the issue is not the interface, but other factors such as market saturation, etc. Either way, these non-interface factors would be uncovered through research.

Comment: Nice recommendation! My favorite book on this topic is [Creating Great Visitor Experiences](https://www.amazon.com/Creating-Great-Visitor-Experiences-Libraries/dp/1598741691) by Stephanie Weaver. The book is written for museums, parks, zoos, and libraries, but I find the concepts map quite well to apps, devices, and services.

Comment: @MichaelHogan Thanks so much for the book recommendation! I was a trained architect before, so tend to think about spaces, physical world and service design. Will definitely read the book.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! That's something that I've been thinking. I need to get away from computers for a while :D

Answer (score 2):

(Note: I like Nicholas’s answer better, but wanted to share another option)

Would it be worth doing field trips to observe people who use your products as they do their jobs?

From your description, it sounds like much of your time is spent inside the company with your team and with data that summarizes how people use your product. It doesn’t sound like you get to spend much time in the field seeing what your users are doing before, during, and after they use your product.

Maybe you can incorporate new features that address things people do to prepare to use your product? Maybe you can make it easier to do the things people do after they use your product? Maybe your product works great, but does unnecessary things when used in real-world situations.

The idea is to use field trips to discover insights about the end user’s goals and needs, so that you’re able to design for what they are trying to accomplish. Too often we get hung up on designing to address the problems people report or optimize a workflow, so we miss opportunities to move people closer toward achieving their goals.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. In fact I want to perform user observations in may daily work.